# How to inflate a layout in HarmonyOS with given context and layout resource id?

Tags: java, android, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, harmonyos

I am working on a HarmonyOS library where I have to inflate a layout with a given
layout resource id: int layoutRes and context: Context context.

In android, the same thing is done using

```
LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(layoutRes, this, true);
```

code in android app:

[image]

What is the alternative for HarmonyOS?

Answer (score 2):

Alternative for **LayoutInflater** is **LayoutScatter** in HarmonyOS. Usage is as follows

```java
LayoutScatter.getInstance(context).parse(layoutRes, this, true);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `LayoutScatter.getInstance(Context context).parse(int xmlId, ComponentContainer root, boolean attachToRoot)` to implement this.

The following is the sample code for your reference:

```
<DirectionalLayout

    ohos:id="$+id:root_dir_layout"

    xmlns:ohos="http://schemas.huawei.com/res/ohos"

    ohos:height="match_parent"

    ohos:width="match_parent"

    ohos:orientation="vertical"
    >
</DirectionalLayout>


private void initView() {

    if (findComponentById(ResourceTable.Id_root_dir_layout)!= null &&

        findComponentById(ResourceTable.Id_root_dir_layout) instanceof DirectionalLayout) {

        rootDirectionalLayout = (DirectionalLayout) findComponentById(ResourceTable.Id_root_dir_layout);

        DirectionalLayout contentComponent = (DirectionalLayout) LayoutScatter.getInstance(

                getContext()).parse(ResourceTable.Layout_dialog_delete, null, false);

        rootDirectionalLayout.addComponent(contentComponent);

    }

}
```

For more details, pls kindly refer to [Docs](https://developer.harmonyos.com/en/docs/documentation/doc-references/layoutscatter-0000001054199990).